# When is apache Storm 2.0 expected to be released?

Tags: apache-storm

Apache Storm 2.0 SNAPSHOT has been tagged on github for a long time (years?) but isn't available for download and I cant find an ETA/roadmap.

My understanding was 2.0 removed a lot of clojure and improved performance (I might be wrong on the later), but is 2.0 dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storm 2.0 has been released now.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the mailing lists for news. See https://storm.apache.org/getting-help.html.

Regarding Storm 2.0.0, a couple of release candidates have been up for votes recently. It will probably be released before too long.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I found that later (after realizing that their ancient google group had moved) https://lists.apache.org/list.html?*@storm.apache.org:lte=1M:%222.0%22 .
They're now at RC3 so maybe a final 2.0 in november